# How do I compare two numbers in android?

Tags: android

My code gets a folder's size and stores the size in `long A`, when you open my app. On the second time you open it, it would then do the same, but store it in `long B`. After this, It is supposed to compare old size with the new size, by doing this, I am able to determine if the file has been modified, or tempered with.

```
private long A;
private long B;
private boolean AorB = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/X ADB/");
    long size = getFolderSize(file);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(size), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    // store size in A and then B and then A and so on
    if (AorB == true) {
        // assign value to A
        A = getFolderSize(file);
        AorB = false;
    } else {
        // assign value to B
        B = getFolderSize(file);
        AorB = true;
    }
    // compare old size with new size
    if (A == B) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "equal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "unequal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

// get directory size
public static long getFolderSize(File dir) {
    long size = 0;
    for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            size += file.length();
        } else
            size += getFolderSize(file);
    }
    return size;
}
```

}

The real problem is, my toast always says unequal, every time I open my app, I didn't even change or modify any file that would effect the size. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [**SharedPreference**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to persist the value when you close your app.

```
// Don't forget to define the variable. 
// You may use whatever name you like.
private static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "my_shared_pref";
```

#### Saving Data

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor 
       = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putLong("size", size);
editor.commit();
```

#### Load Data

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
long loadedSize = prefs.getLong("size", 0);
```

Comment: @FatB00b You are opening and closing the app, you need to be able to persist the size.

Comment: @FatB00b That is a variable that you need to define. Let me update my answer so that you can see.

Comment: @FatB00b Nice! I am glad it helped you.